# Select elements starting and ending with same name JQuery

Tags: jquery

Probably this is already answered but i cant find.

I need to show more then 200-300 images with 3-6 textfield for every image, 
I like user to be able to select ALL images with same second element.

Example: select images image[487][1], image[488][1], images[489][1],images[something][1].. all elements where subelement is "1".

```
<input name="image[487][1]" type="textfield" >
<input name="image[487][8]" type="textfield" >
<input name="image[487][9]" type="textfield" >
<input name="image[487][11]" type="textfield" >

<input name="image[488][1]" type="textfield" >
<input name="image[488][8]" type="textfield" >
<input name="image[488][9]" type="textfield" >
<input name="image[488][11]" type="textfield" >
```

What i already done is i use regEx and each loop. But i am sure there is better way.

```
$('input[name^="images"]').each(function() {
      var regExp = /\[([^)]+)\]/;
      var matches = regExp.exec($(this).attr('name'));

  var numb = matches[1].substring(matches[1].indexOf('[')+1, matches[1].length);
      if(parseInt(numb)==1)
          // DO SOMETHING HERE

 });
```

Thanks and please suggest if i can change title or something else for easier search in the future.

Comment: Have you considered using a class attribute to identify only the ones ending in 1?

Comment: the first number is IMAGE-ID the second is SIZE-ID, both are dinamicly created from db.

And probably i can do it with class="somename-SIZE-ID"
and then get it like that.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try this, starts with and ends with selector

```
$('input[name^="images"][name$="[1]"]')
```

Answer (score 1):

KISS = Keep It Simple and Succint 
If your elements are dynamically generated and you need to identify a lot of them, why not generate also a class attribute?
RegEx parsing is inefficient and it is better avoided.

Add a class attribute to identify those specific images